# hp lap top notebook not responding replaced hard drive because it died

Tags: laptop

while replacing the hard drive I broke the mother board  so I put in a new board  now all I get is boot device not found  and please install operating system on your hard drive  so if I buy a 8.1 operating system windows disc will this fix this  problem

Comment: Did you copy your old drive's contents to the new one? What sort of damage did you do to the mainboard that necessitated replacing it? You can't buy Windows 8 any longer, and anyone offering to sell you a Windows 8 disk is cheating you and you'll probably end up with viruses loaded into that disk. Does the BIOS see your hard drive?